# Как в регулярном выражении указать запятую, после которой идёт пробел

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать, чтобы регулярка

```
RegExp("(0|[1-9][0-9,]*)", "g")
```

Игнорировала запятую, после которой идёт пробел, а с остальными работала так же, как и раньше.

```js
console.log( "1? 2! 3,3, 4".match(RegExp("(0|[1-9][0-9,]*)", "g")) )
```

Делает `[1, 2, 3,3,, 4]`, а нужно `[1, 2, 3,3, 4]`.

Comment: Лучше привести задачу полностью, так будет больше вариантов решения. И хорошо бы примеры текста.

Comment: Строка  "1? 2! 3,3, 4".match(RegExp("(0|[1-9][0-9,]*)", "g")) Делает [1, 2, 3,3,, 4], а нужно [1, 2, 3,3, 4]

Comment: Я не уверен что у тебя за задача, но для решения твоего примера подойдет что-то типа этого: `(?:\d(?:,(?! ))?)+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку опциональная часть с запятой может быть только одна (если это разделитель дробной части, а не разделитель порядков), возможно, этого хватит:

```js
console.log(
  "1? 2! 3,3, 4".match(
    /0|[1-9]\d*(?:,\d+)?/g
  )
);
```

Comment: извиняюсь, не понял Вашего комментария, часть с запятой может быть не одна, но не буду убирать галочку, т.к. некорректно задал вопрос

Comment: Вы можете уточнить. По вашему примеру можно заключить, что числа разделяются запятой с пробелом, но среди них встречаются дроби, в которых дробная часть отделена запятой (и она ведь может быть только одна?). Если это не так, нужно и правда добавить информации.

Comment: могут быть числа, вроде 1,000,000,000, 1,000 и т.д.

Comment: Тогда это разделитель порядков, а не дробной части? Но в таком случае для числа 3,3 он ведь не подходит? Не может же один знак разделять и порядки, и дроби. Обычно для одного используется точка, для другого запятая (в разных языках по-разному).

Comment: В моём случае и 3,3 подходит, не подходят только запятые с пробелом

Comment: Тогда должно быть достаточно сменить последний квантификатор: `/0|[1-9]\d*(?:,\d+)*/g`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое

Answer (score 0):

По видимому, нужно найти последовательность чисел без начальных нулей.

В таком случае необходимо использовать

```js
const text = "1? 2! 3,3, 4";
const intrx = String.raw`(?:0|[1-9]\d*)`;
console.log(text.match(RegExp(`${intrx}(?:,${intrx})*`, 'g')))
```

Регулярное выражение будет выглядеть так:

```
/(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:,(?:0|[1-9]\d*))*/g
```

**Подробности**

- `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` - `0` или цифра от `1` до `9` а потом ноль и более любых цифр
- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей подмаски:

  - `,` - запятая
  - `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` - `0` или цифра от `1` до `9` а потом ноль и более любых цифр
- `)*` - ноль и более повторов

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Rkokr4/1).